# Error while setting up SkLearn: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, scikit-learn, canopy

To install the sklearn module, i have ran the setup.py in the module.

But i take the error:

```
(a long repetition of that):    
C:\Users\Asqan\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.pyc in is_string(s)

394 
395 def is_string(s):
--> 396     return isinstance(s, str)
397 
398 def all_strings(lst):
```

`RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object `

I have tried to increment the stack depth by:

`import sys 
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)`

But then i get another error that says that the kernel does not response en has crashed. If i set it to 5000, it works but then the program does not response.

I use Canopy.

Here you see the `setup.py` which causes the error:

```
import os
from os.path import join
import warnings
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000) # or 5000

def configuration(parent_package='', top_path=None):
from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
from numpy.distutils.system_info import get_info, BlasNotFoundError
import numpy

libraries = []
if os.name == 'posix':
    libraries.append('m')

config = Configuration('sklearn', parent_package, top_path)

config.add_subpackage('__check_build')
config.add_subpackage('svm')
config.add_subpackage('datasets')
config.add_subpackage('datasets/tests')
config.add_subpackage('feature_extraction')
config.add_subpackage('feature_extraction/tests')
config.add_subpackage('cluster')
config.add_subpackage('cluster/tests')
config.add_subpackage('cluster/bicluster')
config.add_subpackage('cluster/bicluster/tests')
config.add_subpackage('covariance')
config.add_subpackage('covariance/tests')
config.add_subpackage('cross_decomposition')
config.add_subpackage('decomposition')
config.add_subpackage('decomposition/tests')
config.add_subpackage("ensemble")
config.add_subpackage("ensemble/tests")
config.add_subpackage('feature_selection')
config.add_subpackage('feature_selection/tests')
config.add_subpackage('utils')
config.add_subpackage('utils/tests')
config.add_subpackage('externals')
config.add_subpackage('mixture')
config.add_subpackage('mixture/tests')
config.add_subpackage('gaussian_process')
config.add_subpackage('gaussian_process/tests')
config.add_subpackage('neighbors')
config.add_subpackage('neural_network')
config.add_subpackage('preprocessing')
config.add_subpackage('manifold')
config.add_subpackage('metrics')
config.add_subpackage('semi_supervised')
config.add_subpackage("tree")
config.add_subpackage("tree/tests")
config.add_subpackage('metrics/tests')
config.add_subpackage('metrics/cluster')
config.add_subpackage('metrics/cluster/tests')
config.add_subpackage('metrics/cluster/bicluster')
config.add_subpackage('metrics/cluster/bicluster/tests')

# add cython extension module for hmm
config.add_extension(
    '_hmmc',
    sources=['_hmmc.c'],
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
    libraries=libraries,
)
config.add_extension(
    '_isotonic',
    sources=['_isotonic.c'],
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
    libraries=libraries,
)

# some libs needs cblas, fortran-compiled BLAS will not be sufficient
blas_info = get_info('blas_opt', 0)
if (not blas_info) or (
        ('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1) in blas_info.get('define_macros', [])):
    config.add_library('cblas',
                       sources=[join('src', 'cblas', '*.c')])
    warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

# the following packages depend on cblas, so they have to be build
# after the above.
config.add_subpackage('linear_model')
config.add_subpackage('utils')

# add the test directory
config.add_subpackage('tests')

return config

if __name__ == '__main__':
from numpy.distutils.core import setup
setup(**configuration(top_path='').todict())
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: @larsmans question updated

Comment: Looks like a bug in NumPy or Canopy, changing tags.